# this await throwing unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I have a simple `async` function. It just sends a request and returns the data:

```
export const updatePanorama = async ({ commit }, payload) => {
  const urlEnd = '/v1/pano/update'
  const type = 'post'
  const resp = await api.asyncRequest(urlEnd, type, payload)
  commit('SET_PANORAMA', resp.data)
  return resp
}
```

And this is how I'm using the function:

```
handleUpdatePanorama (panorama) {
  const payload = {}
  this.updatePanorama(payload).then(resp => {
    this.setIsLoading(false)
    this.handleAlert('updateSuccess', 'success')
  }).catch(() => {
    this.setIsLoading(false)
    this.handleAlert('updateError', 'danger')
  })
},
```

The problem is, the code after `catch` runs if there's an error inside `then`. But this way I don't know whether the catch error is an request error or and error triggered by the code inside then.

I'm trying `try` and `catch` to solve that problem:

```
handleUpdatePanorama (panorama) {
  try {
    const payload = {}
    const resp = await this.updatePanorama(payload)
    console.log('resp:', resp)
    this.setIsLoading(false)
    this.handleAlert('updateSuccess', 'success')
  } catch (err) {
    this.setIsLoading(false)
    this.handleAlert('updateError', 'danger')
  })
},
```

However, I get an unexpected token error in this line: `await this.updatePanorama(payload)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can't use await unless the function is `async`

Comment: FYI, `async/await` is not part of ES7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is, the code after `catch` runs if there's an error inside `then`

The solution for that is to not use `catch`, but the second `then` parameter. Have a look at the [difference between `.then(…).catch(…)` and `.then(…, …)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572) for details.

> I'm trying `try` and `catch` to solve that problem

That won't work, the `catch` clause will still be called if there's an exception thrown by `setIsLoading` or `handleAlert`.

> I get an unexpected token error. What am I doing wrong?

You have not declared the `handleUpdatePanorama` method as `async`.

To mitigate the issues and fix the syntax, you could write

```
async handleUpdatePanorama (panorama) {
  var result
  try {
    const payload = {}
    const resp = await this.updatePanorama(payload)
    console.log('resp:', resp)
    result = ['updateSuccess', 'success']
  } catch (err) {
    result = ['updateError', 'danger']
  } finally {
    this.setIsLoading(false)
  }
  this.handleAlert(...result)
},
```

Comment: They say that using the second then parameter is an anti-pattern?

Comment: `They` don't always know what `they` are talking about :p - it has its uses

Comment: @alex Who is *they*? No, it's not an antipattern when you *want* this (in other use cases undesirable) behaviour.

Comment: @Bergi By they I meant the Internet - okay, maybe you're right.

Comment: @alex Hey, *I'm* the internet here! :-P

Answer (score 1):

If you need to handle errors specifically from updatePanorama, use the second argument to .then(onSuccess, onError)

```
handleUpdatePanorama(panorama) {
    const payload = {}
    this.updatePanorama(payload).then(resp => {
        this.setIsLoading(false)
        this.handleAlert('updateSuccess', 'success')
    }, err => {
        // handle error from updatePanorama
        // you can throw err if you also want to handle the error in .catch()
    }).catch(() => {
        this.setIsLoading(false)
        this.handleAlert('updateError', 'danger')
    })
}
```

note: if you `return` (or have no return statement) from the error handler, any subsequent `.then(onSuccess` will execute, if you throw an error (or return Promise.reject() for example, then the .catch() code will also run